# How to delete a dictionary in a list, if the same dictionary is in another list (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, list-comprehension

I have two lists that include same dictionaries in the format of:

List 1:

```
[{'url': u'http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-08-17/you-can-get-a-50-phone-from-amazon-if-you-don-t-mind-the-ads','title': u'You Can Get a $50 Phone From Amazon, If You Don\u2019t Mind the Ads'}, {'url': u'http://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2016-08-18/uber-s-first-self-driving-fleet-arrives-in-pittsburgh-this-month-is06r7on', 'title': u'Uber\u2019s First Self-Driving Fleet Arrives in Pittsburgh This Month'}]
```

List 2:

```
[{'url': u'http://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-08-17/you-can-get-a-50-phone-from-amazon-if-you-don-t-mind-the-ads', 'title': u'You Can Get a $50 Phone From Amazon, If You Don\u2019t Mind the Ads'}]
```

What I wanted to do:
I would like to delete the dictionary(both url and title) in list 1 which is also present in list2.

I have tried the following,

```
list1[:] = [d for d in list1 if d.get('title') != (fail for fail in list2 if fail.get('title'))]
```

but couldn't manage to do it

Expected Result:

```
list1 = [{'url': u'http://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2016-08-18/uber-s-first-self-driving-fleet-arrives-in-pittsburgh-this-month-is06r7on', 'title': u'Uber\u2019s First Self-Driving Fleet Arrives in Pittsburgh This Month'}]
```

Comment: what should be the output?

Comment: Just added to the question @HarshaBiyani

Comment: Could you please restate what you would like to do? It is a little hard to understand.

Comment: I want to remove the dictionaries that are common with list2 from list1.@Mr.goosberry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just do a simple comparison:

```
>>> final = [i for i in one if i not in two]
>>> final
[{'url': u'http://www.bloomberg.com/news/features/2016-08-18/uber-s-first-self-driving-fleet-arrives-in-pittsburgh-this-month-is06r7on', 'title': u'Uber\u2019s First Self-Driving Fleet Arrives in Pittsburgh This Month'}]
```

Then you can do `list1 = final` if you really want.

Comment: How neat and concise!

Comment: Note: This is `O(n*m)` (where `n` is the size of `list1` and `m` is the size of `list2`, making it `O(n^2)` for similarly sized lists), since it has to scan `list2` linearly once for each element in `list1`. Depending on requirements, it could be possible to do a `O(n)` preprocessing pass on `list2` such that the `list1` filtering step can perform lookups in `O(1)`, getting a total `O(n)`. Of course, if the lists are small, it hardly matters.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want `list1` to consist only of the entries whose title does not exist in `list2`. This is probably best done with a two step process, to avoid repeated linear scans of `list2` for each element in `list1`:

```
# Make a set of all titles defined by the dicts in list2
titles_in_list2 = {d['title'] for d in list2 if 'title' in d}

# Filter the contents of list1 to only items with titles not found in list2
list1[:] = [d for d in list1 if d.get('title') not in titles_in_list2]
```

Note: The `.get` call in the second comprehension, and the `if` check in the first aren't needed if all entries are guaranteed to have a `title` key defined. The `.get` would become straight lookup, `d['title'] not in titles_in_list2`, and the `if 'title' in d` check would be dropped entirely. You also don't need the slice assignment unless other references to `list1` might exist and must be changed; if that's not a concern, `list1 = [...]` is fine.

Comment: This code worked perfectly too. I wanted to also remove the 'urls' from the list1 as well.

Comment: @Pythoner1234: This is removing the whole `dict` if the titles match, which eliminates the urls and titles at once. You could change it to construct a check set of `urls` and test against that if you want, or construct both a title and url check set and delete overlaps on either, but that just changes which `dict`s get dropped; if the `dict` is dropped, you drop all its keys and values, not just the one you tested against after all.

Answer (score 0):

Burhan Khalid's answer is perfect.
In case, you want a solution matching to your line of previous thoughts, here it is :

`list1 = [d for d in list1 if d.get('title') not in [f.get('title') for f in list2]]`